# problem opening ssrs 2017 report with visual studio 2010 or 2012 or 2013

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2016

Problem opening ssrs 2017 report with visual studio 2010 or visual studio 2012

I am in the process of determining if ssrs 2010 and ssrs 2012 reports can be opened in Visual Studio 2017 and I found this to be succesful.

However I  am now trying to open the ssrs 2017 report using Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio 2012, and/or Visual Studio 2013 since that it what my co-workers currently use.

I am gettin getting the error message ' One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly. Please see the Output Window for details'.

What I see s the C':\Census\Census.rptproj : error : there is an error in the xml document (2, 2). This probably has to do with version numbers.

Thus can you tell me a ssrs 2017 report can be opened in Visual Studio 2010 or Visual Studio 2012 or Visual Studio 2013? If so, can youy tell me 
how to accomplish my goal?

Comment: If you are using VS just for Reports development.. just download VS data tools (SSDT) for 2017 (it's free). You don't need the full version to create SSRS reports.. Or you can also use Report Designer..

Comment: I am already using ssdt 2017 and that is not the issue. The issue is can ssrs  2017 reports be  opened using ssdt 2010 or 2012 or 2013? If so, how do you accomplish this goal/

Comment: hmm.. you can downgrade the rdl file to a previous version and open it by editing the xml for the rdl.. but then you will have only one version of reporting server right?

Comment: Yes all the ssrs 201o to ssrs 2017 reports run successfully on the same 2016 report server. Would you tell me or show me how to downgrade an ssrs 2017 report to ssrs 2012 or ssrs 2013?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.

Before you do anything.. **back up your .rdl file first**

Open the RDL in XML (any editor is fine)

Line 2 will have something like this in your new report :

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2017/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

you need to change it to something like the following - I'm not entirely sure what year you want

```
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2012/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
```

After this.. go to the bottom of the xml file and remove the follwing tag  as well as everything in between the tags

```
<ReportParametersLayout>

 </ReportParametersLayout>
```

the reason for this is, only 2016 on wards allowed for parameter layout modification. Previously it was not available.

Now save the xml file.

Open the rdl in BIDS or whatever tool you prefer to use. Should work.

another alternative is to look at this answer :

[How to Create SSRS 2012 Reports using Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381535/how-to-create-ssrs-2012-reports-using-visual-studio-2019)