# How to Create SSRS 2012 Reports using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services

The customer I am consulting at is running their ERP and SSRS on SQL Server 2012. They're currently using Visual Studio 2010 Shell to create their SSRS reports.

I've been able to upgrade my Visual Studio to 2019 Professional. I can create SSRS reports in VS 2019, but when I try and upload the file to the reporting services web site, it fails saying I'm using a new version of Reporting Services (DUH).

Is there a way I can create SSRS 2012 reports (RDL) using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: How are you trying to "upload" the file? Normally you deploy the project/report, not upload it.

Comment: As far as I am aware, as well, the Reporting Service Extension for Visual Studio 2019 (there is no SSDT any more)  supports SQL Server 2012+. Certainly I haven't read any material that says otherwise (I *normally* keep up to date on these, like when Microsoft (stupidly) removed it from SSDT 2017 in V 15.8.1 and promptly returned it in V15.9.0), nor have I heard anything from other communities to suggest it does not support 2012.

Comment: Larnu, yoe when i do a regular Upload File it tells me the RDL File is newer and cannot upload

Comment: Here are the Versions i have installed on Visual Studio 2019 Pro --                      SSIS 15.0.1528.0, SSDT 16.061908.27190, SSRS 15.0.1528.0

Comment: Again, what do you mean "upload". Why aren't you using the deploy process?

Comment: I apologize, I have the SSRS  website running HTTP://SERVER/Reports_MSSQL2012/Pages/Folder.aspx When I Click [Upload File] Select my Report [.RDL] File after I click "OK" I get this Error Msg on the Web Site:  "The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace

Comment: This just leads me back to the question I've already asked twice; Why are you not using the Deploy feature. I don't mean to offend, but as consultant you should be aware of that functionality already, and how to use it.

Comment: [Publishing Reports to a Report Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/reports/publishing-reports-to-a-report-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 3):

In the Reporting Properties (DEBUG --> Reporting Properties), change the **Target Server Version** setting and choose **SQL Server 2008 R2, 2012 or 2014**.

[image]

Comment: AND you have to upload the *built* RDL file from the bin folder now instead of the original RDL.

Comment: @DaleK You saved my day. The `.rdl` in folder `Reports` is built in the latest version of 2016. The `.rdl` in `bin` folder is the file which built based on *Target Server Version*.